# Looping through API requests to log a value

Tags: python

I am working with an API that paginates results of a request, handily the API also generates some 'hypermedia' values that contains information on the pagination; one of these values is 'next_page'.

I am trying to create a loop that takes a request, logs this 'next_page' value, then runs another request using the value of 'next_page', and logs the next page, so on and so on, until the value of 'next_page' = 'None'.

Here's my function so far, but this is only populating one item in the list, when there should be 3.

```
pages = []
def build_requests(request):
    request = 'https://api.performancehorizon.com'+request
    job = requests.get(request, headers=headers, params=params)
    req = job.json()

    hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']

    if hypermedia_np != 'None':
        next_page = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']
        pages.append(next_page)
        job = requests.get('https://api.performancehorizon.com'+next_page, headers=headers, params=params)
        req = job.json()
    else: print("Done!")
```

How can I change my code to loop over this job until the value of 'next_page' is 'None'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below modified code

```
pages = []
def build_requests(request):
    request = 'https://api.performancehorizon.com' + request
    job = requests.get(request, headers=headers, params=params)
    req = job.json()

    hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']

    while hypermedia_np is not None or hypermedia_np != 'None':
        next_page = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']
        if next_page is not None or next_page != 'None':
            pages.append(next_page)
            job = requests.get('https://api.performancehorizon.com' + next_page, headers=headers, params=params)
            req = job.json()
            hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']
        else:
            hypermedia_np = None
    print("Done!")
```

Or you can use this simplified version, this should also work for your case

```
pages = []
def build_requests(request):
    request = 'https://api.performancehorizon.com' + request
    job = requests.get(request, headers=headers, params=params)
    req = job.json()

    hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']

    while hypermedia_np is not None or hypermedia_np != 'None':
        pages.append(hypermedia_np)
        job = requests.get('https://api.performancehorizon.com' + hypermedia_np, headers=headers, params=params)
        req = job.json()
        hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']

    print("Done!")
```

Comment: Thank you @Tanzeel - this is working, but I am getting the error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str` - it looks like the loop still tried to append 'None' as the final step, how can I stop this?